# Separate vpn and regular eth traffic

Tags: vpn

In kubuntu 22.04, I have two net devices as below, how to set a list of links go through ppp0, while other not matching links go through eht1? and this rule only effective when ppp0 is connected.

```
default dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 100
```

Comment: How do you want to differentiate the traffic?

Comment: I have a list of websites, I'd like them go through VPN ppp0

Comment: The short answer is that you *can't*; routing decisions is based on IP addresses, not URLs or DNS names. There's not a 1:1 mapping either. Easiest solution is probably some proxy such as Squid, or a solution involving different browsers and network namespaces.

Comment: I can generate IP from URLs by dnsmasq and ipset?

Comment: Theoretically, but you risk casting a too wide net. Many sites may direct to the same IP owned by e.g. Cloudflare.

Comment: Any guide? I can take a try